# Firebase Realtime Database billing for unauthorized request especially for overheads

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

i'm flutter-fire dev, 4-season-old. Recently i'm diving into security ideas of Firebase. It is not difficult to implement security rules with Firebase Auth, since we've got plenty of SO questions and official docs.

My question today is about Firebase security rules, but more about Firebase billing. Let's say we've defended a bunch of malicious restful attacks containing wrong access tokens by using auth-context security rules. And there actually happened zero read or write.

In this case, how can i calculate the billing of my rtdb? I have a [calculator](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Me2TVc6HnARLOCkGSWPIi6m3VjGMM2-yW0WXCgxcQYc/edit#gid=0) from a member of the community, but i couldn't have figured out how to calculate the cost of unauthorized reqs exactly, since the calculator does not provide more details about overhead ATM. I understand that there's a bunch of things subject to the [rtdb billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing). But it seems like there is no official specific description for the billing policy or calculation principle for the unauthorized reqs.

The reason why we should be always aware of rtdb download cost is the cost consists of many additional huge amount of data for the security purpose and so on. Since such additional data costs a lot(which is the reason why we prefer to use stream to extremely reduce such overhead-like costs), i think those attacks can potentially cost a lot of cash even though they cannot read or write to our json tree.

So, through this question, i hope to make clear of below two things:

1. Comparing to authorized requests, Does unauthorized requests cost the same additional fees like overhead and so on?
2. If 1. is true, then how can we exactly calculate the fee? It is hard for me to [understand](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) why there is no official guide to separately calculate the download fee itself and overhead fee even if the OH actually cost devs bunch of dollars.

I guess some parts of this question might not be clear enough, so comments are really appreciated. Hope this question reach to Firebase gurus in the community! Thank you in advance [:

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific line in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing) which says

> "Outbound traffic includes connection and encryption overhead from all
> database operations and data downloaded through database reads. Both
> database reads and writes can lead to connection costs on your bill.
> **All traffic to and from your database, including operations denied by security rules, leads to billable costs."**

From this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#firestore-rules) ,

> You're also charged for any reads required to evaluate Cloud Firestore
> Security Rules you've added to your database”. If these do not require
> a read, then this should not require any overhead connecting to the
> database.

From this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#firestore-rules) ,

> For mobile and web client libraries, if your Cloud Firestore Security
> Rules use exists(), get(), or getAfter() to read one or more documents
> from your database, you are charged for additional reads as follows:

- You are charged for reads that are necessary to evaluate your Cloud
  Firestore Security Rules. For example, if your rules refer to three
  documents, but Cloud Firestore only has to read two of those
  documents to evaluate your rules, you will be charged for two
  additional reads for the dependent documents.
- You are only charged one read per dependent document even if your
  rules refer to that document more than once.
- You are charged for rule evaluation only once per request.
- As a result, it can cost less to read multiple documents than to read
  documents one at a time, because reading multiple documents requires
  fewer requests.
- When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for rule
  evaluation in all of the following cases:

  1. When you issue the query.
  2. Each time the query results are updated.
  3. Any time the user's device goes offline, then comes back online.
  4. Any time you update your rules.
  5. Any time you update the dependent documents in your rules.”

**Note** : You are also charged for the network bandwidth used by your Cloud Firestore requests. Incoming network bandwidth (network ingress) is free. The network bandwidth cost of a Cloud Firestore request depends on the request’s response size, the location of your Cloud Firestore database, and the destination of the response but Requests denied by your Cloud Firestore Security Rules do not count towards [network bandwidth usage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#network).